# Use Perl to Modify a Bitstream

Tags: perl, pdf, bit-manipulation, lzw, bitstream

How can I re-pack bits into a bitstream after modifying them in Perl?

I'm currently using the following to unpack:

```
my $bits = 5;
my $code = '';

foreach my $i (reverse 0..$bits-1) {
    $code <<= 1;
    $code  |= vec($data,$i,1);
}
```

For example, the output might be 16.

**EDIT:**

This question relates to the data block of a GIF image.

What I'm trying to do is to pad the LZW codes to match the length required by PDF's `LZWDecode` method.

`LZWDecode` expects 8-bit images in which the `<Clear>` code is 256 and the `<End>` code is 257 ([PDF Reference](http://partners.adobe.com/public/developer/en/pdf/PDFReference13.pdf), page 44.)

For 5-bit images, codes 0-31 map to colors in the image's global color table, `<Clear>` is 32 and `<End>` is 33.

So I need to re-pack the bitstream so that codes 0-31 remain the same, but 32+ are offset by 256-32.

I'm using ActiveState Perl for Windows.

Comment: That did help. From what you added, we can deduce the field doesn't always start at bit zero and we can deduce that you don't want to clobber the other bits in the byte. It also tells us that you want to read 8 bits at a time even though you're currently reading 5. Finally, it tells us you want to manipulate a whole sequence of fields (not just one), and that you don't need to deal with arbitrary field sizes. But it doesn't tell us how to handle padding. What do you do with the rest of the bits?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
# Unpack from 8 bit fields.
my @vals = unpack('C*', $bytes);

... transform @vals into 5 bit values here ...

# Pack to 5 bit fields.
my $bits = join '', map substr(pack('B*', $val), -5), @vals;
$bits .= '0' x (-length($bits) % 8);  # Pad with zeros to byte boundary
$bytes = pack('B*', $bits);
```

Comment: Thanks, ikegami, for your ongoing feedback. Based on the information I provided, I have marked this as answered, but it actually doesn't address my needs. I have started a [new thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11108579/use-perl-to-add-gif-image-other-than-8-bit-to-pdf) to hopefully better phrase my objectives, and I'd appreciate it if you could provide some comments.